# ActiveRecord class (enum) behaving incorrectly with patch in config/initializers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm using ruby 2.2.3 and rails 4.2.4.

Background: I need the ability to re-use values across enums within the same model so I have patched in the latest version of Active Record's `enum.rb` as `config/initializers/enum_patch.rb` since they are adding prefix/suffix support in Rails 5 which will enable this functionality.

Issue: After patching in the code, Enum is no longer working correctly. See below:

```
class GatheringSession < ActiveRecord::Base
  GatheringStates = %i(ready running finished errored)
  enum :gathering_state => GatheringStates

  ...
end
```

Console (no patch). Correct behaviour:

```
2.2.3 :001 > gs2 = GatheringSession.last
 => #<GatheringSession id: 120, gathering_state: 2 ... > 
2.2.3 :002 > gs2.gathering_state
 => "finished" 
2.2.3 :003 > gs2.ready?
 => false 
2.2.3 :004 > gs2.finished?
 => true 
2.2.3 :005 > gs2.ready!
 => true 
2.2.3 :007 > gs2.ready?
 => true 
2.2.3 :008 > gs2.finished?
 => false 
2.2.3 :009 > gs2.finished!
 => true 
2.2.3 :010 > gs2.finished?
 => true
```

Console (patch):

```
2.2.3 :001 > gs2 = GatheringSession.last
 => #<GatheringSession id: 120, gathering_state: 2 ... > 
2.2.3 :002 > gs2.gathering_state
 => 2 
2.2.3 :003 > gs2.ready?
 => false 
2.2.3 :004 > gs2.finished?
 => false 
2.2.3 :005 > gs2.ready!
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
     SQL (0.8ms)  UPDATE `gathering_sessions` SET `gathering_state` = 'ready', `updated_at` = '2015-10-31 00:28:36' WHERE `gathering_sessions`.`id` = 120
     Mysql2::Error: Incorrect integer value: 'ready' for column 'gathering_state' at row 1: UPDATE `gathering_sessions` SET `gathering_state` = 'ready', `updated_at` = '2015-10-31 00:28:36' WHERE `gathering_sessions`.`id` = 120
   (0.1ms)  ROLLBACK
     ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: Incorrect integer value: 'ready' for column 'gathering_state' at row 1: UPDATE `gathering_sessions` SET `gathering_state` = 'ready', `updated_at` = '2015-10-31 00:28:36' WHERE `gathering_sessions`.`id` = 120
     ...
     from /Users/william/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/persistence.rb:263:in `update!'
     from /Users/william/code/repo/config/initializers/enum_patch.rb:193:in `block (4 levels) in enum'
```

After doing a little bit of testing, I've realized the problem is not the new code that I've patched in, but the fact that I'm patching in code period. Even when using the same code that is shipped with Rails 4.2.4 ([here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rails/rails/8e103d182412b9e9e5bd28c17bb83759882a4389/activerecord/lib/active_record/enum.rb)) I get the same (incorrect) behaviour.

Does anyone have an idea why this is happening and how I can fix it?

Comment: How did you patch? Please show some code.

Comment: I literally copy/pasted the most recent code of `enum.rb` into `enum_patch.rb`. Code is [HERE](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/enum.rb)